# Error while loading question on SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

After creating a post in SE Android app, I can't open it for some time as it says "Failed to load question". This started happening suddenly, a week ago. Now I have to use the website. (It loads the question In the website).

I am using SE app on Android 5.0

Comment: One of the oldest and most irritating bugs in the app, no doubt.

Comment: The error message is "failed to load question" and not "question is unavailable". It happens infrequently.

Comment: Pretty sure it is the same bug and only the message text changed.